# I need to count number of dates in a range, that when compared to one specific date are more than a particular number of days (56 in my case)

Tags: excel-formula, countif

[image: Table image of data with headings: Sr No. - Employee Name - Start Date - End Date - Total Days]

How I see it what I need is =countif(C:C,"datedif(12-09-2015,C:C,"d")>56")
My best guess is that within the datedif brackets I can't enter a date as C:C.

I keep getting an error message or a zero.

What I want to achieve is to have a monthly (1-30/31) table that shows how many people were working on that day that had been there for more than 56 days. So the end table would look something like this:

[image: Table of end result: Showing days of month in x-axis and location in y-axis]

Comment: How to place people in `Locations X` if `Location X` is not present in first table?

Answer (score 0):

[use array `=SUM(IF())` instead of `=COUNTIF()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/275166)

Firs of all create an IF finction that return TRUE when your conditions are met:

- in cell `F2` put: `=IF("20/09/2015"-C2:C12 > 56)` and confirm with **`CTRL+Shift+enter`** to create an array formula
  you should get: `TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE`
- once you know it works as intended, you can just wrap it in a single-cell sum. In cell `G2` put: `=SUM(IF("20/09/2015"-C2:C12 > 56))` and confirm with **`CTRL+Shift+enter`**. You will have a single cell this time, with a result of 3

This should be enough to get you started. In your case I suggest you store the "1,2,3,4,5..." day numbers in results sheet as dates, formatted to display just the day number, and then reference that directly in each countif